# How do I set an alert on a folder but not on its subfolders?

Tags: sharepoint, directory, alert, subdirectory

:)
I'd like to set an alert on my Sharepoint 2013 site for a specific folder... It has a special property and I would like to be alerted when someone else changes this property. But I DON'T want to be alerted when there's anything else changed inside the folder or its subfolders (e. g. when there's a new doc created in the folder etc.), as that would be way too many alerts. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to achieve that programmatically or with OOTB functionality?

Comment: preferably without any programming...

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. The only way to prevent getting overwhelmed by too many alerts is by specifying a custom view with according filters in your list/document library. After you created an additional view (next to the standard view) you can select the trigger ``(alert me when...) 'Someone changes an item that appears in the following view'``. I think that is the closest you can get without any programming.